# How to redirect a RTMP stream to clients

Tags: java, spring, red5

I have a RTMP stream being broadcasted in the same server as my Spring Boot application.

For instance, it can be accessed using

> rtmp://localhost/livestream

And it's a video livestream, broadcasted from a RED5 server. I want to redirect this livestream to any amount of clients that try to request it.

For example:

```
@Service
public class RTMPStreamHandler {

@RequestMapping("/stream") {
public /*Stream Object?*/ getStream() {
   //What should be returned?
   }
}
```

This kind of behaviour is necessary so that I can control when that RTMP stream can be accessed, as it will be live 24hrs, but only accessible in some of them. I'll put that logic on my `Controller`.

How can I setup SpringFramework to read from that RTMP stream and broadcast it to users that try to access that endpoint? Is that a possibility in Spring?

Comment: https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples/tree/master/springmvc have tried this? or are your trying to keep RED5 and spring app running separately and find a much more simple integration method?

Comment: The latter. I want a simple way to multistream a video in rtmp format. Can also be rtsp. I'll be streaming from an Ip Camera, and I'm attempting to re-stream it with red5+spring in rtmp format. I don't want to pass red5 server directly because I might have to block the access based on some rules

Comment: Do you need Java at all for blocking access? It might be easier to just setup a reverse proxy and configure access there with basic auth or ip ranges.

Comment: I need java, because I'll control access to the Stream using Spring. It may be a proxy, can even be HTTP

Answer (score -1):

Try the Red5 Media Server (red5.org), it works with Spring, it may fit your purposes

Comment: I did try, and it doesn't work well with Spring(at least with what I tried to do). Care to ellaborate?